# How to check rsync success in makefile

Tags: makefile, rsync

i have question
i hope here get help

this is my makefile

```
@echo '************  Start  ************'
rsync -av -e "ssh -p 22" --delete --exclude=.git $(shell pwd) $(remote_host_10):$(www_dir)
@make create_version -f $(make_file) n=$(n)
@echo '************   Complete   ************'
```

well, i try to do if rsync retrun successful then do `make create_version -f $(make_file) n=$(n)`

so

i must check rsync results

but i don't know how to do Q_Q

Comment: That's not a makefile. That's a recipe from inside a makefile. make stops if any command in a recipe fails so that should be doing what you want. Is it not working in some way?

Comment: @Etan Reisner Yes.You're right.I should say. when rsync is not updated anything, I do not do make create_version.So I have to confirm it.

This recipe I want to achieve results.

rsync update something then create version number.
when nothing change, do not do anything.

Comment: I don't believe (but could be wrong) that the return code from `rsync` can tell you that. I think you'll need to use the `rsync` output or see if there is a flag to `rsync` that you can use to ask it whether it has any work to do.

Comment: @Etan Reisner,OK~thank u for your comments, i well try to get rsync output. Then test  results on here ^^